# Returning Imageuri=null (but data extras) from camera capture

Tags: android

while debugging the below code, i am getting the value of `picUri` as `null` and i can see as `picUri=null data:"Intent" {act=inline-data (has extras)}"` in trace. Why does picUri is not having the corresponding uri and have data extras?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
            try {
                // use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                // get the Uri for the captured image
                picUri = data.getData();
                                        }
                 }
}
```

Comment: but you have to put capture image url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have received the data in `Bundle` in `onactivityresult` and stored it into a `file` and got the `uri` from that `file` as shown below.

```
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap var_Bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var_Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

try {

    OutputStream out;
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
    File createDir = new File(root+"macro"+File.separator);
    createDir.mkdir();


    File file = new File(root + "macro" + File.separator +"macro.jpg");

    file.createNewFile();
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();

    picUri= Uri.fromFile(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
}
```